# Update Virus Database on S6

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung S6.  I keep getting a message that says I need to update my virus database, that my virus database has not been updated for 26 months (my phone is only 3 months old) and is no longer protecting me from the latest threats.  There is an option to update database and an option to enable all premium features.  Below that there is a security broadcast that lists a virus named a.payment.cola.a and has information on the virus and what kind of threat it is.  This keeps coming up on my phone over and over.  I am not sure if it is legit or is itself a virus.  I have tried googling it, but can't find any info on it.  Is this a virus?  I have Avast security on my phone since I got it and it shows there are no current threats or viruses, but you never know.  Just need to know if I should click to update the database.

Comment: I closed it out.  I will have to wait until it pops up again to do a screen shot, unfortunately.  I don't know what triggers it.  It pops up randomly.  As for what android version I am using, whatever comes on the S6.

Comment: When it happens again, remember the context: have you been browsing a certain website, used a specific app, done a specific task when it popped up? The irregularity you describe rather suggests it's one of those things *wanting you to think it is a virus* and to download the real malware. The fact it speaks of 26 months (with [the phone first released just 10 months ago](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6-6849.php)) adds to it, making it look like a blatant lie. Why would a manufacturer install such an outdated database on his new flagship device?

Comment: You probably downloaded an app that is an AdWare

Comment: Thanks Izzy.  I will remember to include that info.  The 26 months thing seemed strange to me as well as the phones haven't been available that long.  How do I get rid of it then if it is AdWare, which I assume it is?

Comment: No general rule @LeeSprang (‹ dont forget the `@` if you mention someone, or that someone won't be notified ;) We first need to see the context. Could as well be some "malware ad" on some web page you were viewing.

Answer (score 3):

Searching the name of that "virus" returns only results for NQ Security, who are essentially a nobody company [accused of creating spyware](http://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-and-threats/chinese-antivirus-firm-nq-called-massive-fraud/d/d-id/1112075) to trick people into paying for their useless security app.  In my opinion, this is a complete scam.

You should check in Settings → Security (or Safety & Privacy) under Device Administrators and remove any apps that you don't want controlling your device (if present), and then remove anything suspicious under Settings → Applications.  Specifically, remove anything from NQ or any anti-malware software you don't recognize.